# How to get average of views before clicking on advertisement?

Tags: sql, join, hive, average

I've got two tables containing information about viewing and clicking on advertisement by each user:

**Clicks**:

```
userID   Action   Time
123      c        2016-01-08 01:57:00
123      c        2016-01-11 03:17:12
200      c        2016-01-09 02:20:10
332      c        2016-01-12 07:07:07
```

**Views**:

```
userID   Action   Time
123      0        2016-01-07 01:33:00
123      0        2016-01-10 04:12:13
200      w        2016-01-08 02:20:10
332      0        2016-01-09 07:07:07
332      0        2016-01-10 07:07:07
332      0        2016-01-11 07:07:07
```

I want to know what was the average of views before clicking on advertisement first time, second time etc. From the example above:
User `123` clicked first time having only one view before, user `200` also, and user `332` had three views before clicking first time. So the average for the first click is `(1+1+3)/3=1.67`. Only user `123` clicked twice, after two views (in total).

The result I want looks like this:

```
Nr_clicks  Avg_views
1          1.67
2          2
...
```

The `Action` column in `Views` table can take different values (but not `c`), in `Clicks` table is always `c`. I was trying to use `JOIN` with subquery and then average results but I didn't get what I expected.

Comment: Please share what you have tried..

Comment: Basic is this: `select a.userID, a.Action, a.Time, b.Action as Action2, b.Time as Time2 from 
Clicks a  join Views b on Clicks.UserID=Views.UserID and
b.Time<a.Time `. I don't know how to group it and average it... my all attempts are failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it take me some time but I think it works well:

```
select clickcume nr_clicks, avg(view_b) avg_view_before from(
select userid, clickcume, max(viewcume) view_b from(
select a.*, b.time_v, b.viewcume  from   
(
  select userid, time as time_c, 
         count(*) over (partition by userid order by time) as clickcume
  from views) a join 
(
  select userid, time as time_v,
         count(*) over (partition by userid order by time) as viewcume
  from clicks) b 
  on (a.userid=b.userid)
where time_c>=time_v ) c
group by userid, clickcume ) d
group by clickcume
```